# Make many to many fields editable in both object's admin forms

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model with a many-to-many field relating it to another Django model object.

```
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    models.ManyToManyField(B)
```

If I look on A's admin form I will see the name field and a many-to-many widget listing all the B's.

If I look at B's admin form I will see just the name widget.

Is there a way to allow both model's admin form to have a many-to-many widget. I'd like to add A's when I'm looking at B, and I'd like to add B's when I'm looking at A.

Can this be done?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Grokzen/a64321dd69339c42a184

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `MultipleChoiceField`. Django model's `ManyToManyField` is represented as a `MultipleChoiceField`.

Check references.

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types
3. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets

Note: While adding B in A's form, you should create B instance first and then you have to add A to B. else you will get error as B instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.